# Check if git repo is public with HTTP request

Tags: git, gitlab, http-headers, httprequest

For my project, I need to know if a git repo is public or not to do some actions.
I first thought to use HTTP request so I'm using postman and I tried with multiple URLs with HEAD method.

When I'm sending a request, I can't see what in the header can indicate me when it failed or not.

When I send a request to github for a private project, I'm receiving a the status 404 so it's perfect for me cause I know that is a private project.

BUT when I do this for gitlab, I'm receiving the status 200 then I'm redirected.

I would like to know if there is a solution for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, the easiest way to do this is to perform a `GET` request after appending `/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack` to the URL. That's the endpoint which Git uses to get reference information.

If the repo is public, you'll get a 200. You'll likely get a 401 if the repository is private or doesn't exist. Most major hosting providers don't provide information about whether a private repository exists or not until after you've authenticated, so you'll get a 401 either way.

Note that you can't use a `HEAD` request; GitHub returns a 405 Method Not Allowed in that case.

*Example:*
Open Source Repo: **https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git**

*{GET}:* **https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack**

*Example 401:*

```
wget $URL
Connecting to gitlab.com (35.231.145.151:80)
Connecting to gitlab.com (35.231.145.151:443)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

echo $?
1
```

Comment: I encountered the same exact need in order to include a conditional DEPLOY step inside GitLab CI file. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an easy way to fail the deploy step on my master branch if repo is private. I've used this approach in conjunction with environment variable: to find the URL which worked perfectly! here is a snippet: 
```
script:
    - URL="${CI_REPOSITORY_URL:33}/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack"
    - wget $UR
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on GitHub, but just `curl -I https://github.com/user/repo` gave me 200 for a public repo and 404 for private and non-existent repos alike. Which I guess is exactly what OP said. I'm going in circles. But I'm going to add the gitlab tag to the question.

Comment: It definitely works for me on GitHub.  I get a 200 for `curl -v https://github.com/git/git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack` and a 401 if I rewrite it to use a private repo.  You definitely should not make requests to the web interface like you're doing because those will likely be aggressively throttled and you'll probably end up getting a 429 instead.