# Prevent users to push into public repos GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-bash, visual-studio-2022

I'm working on project that uses GitHub to manage source control and it is using a private repository. I want to make sure that whenever me or my teammate made any push that will to go that private repo. Just in case if somebody has turned it public accidently.

**So is there a way to force user to run a command to check whether it is a private repo or not if not don't proceed to push**.

like

git commit -m "commit has done let check if it is private or not"

git check private-- Here we need help

if Yes

git push origin dev

else

echo -- Be careful next time you were trying to push into a public repo

terminated.

Comment: I don't think there is such a think.... but let's see what other say.

Comment: Likely duplicate of eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959589/check-if-git-repo-is-public-with-http-request

Comment: "Just in case if somebody has turned it public accidently."  Set up a webhook so you know it's turned public.  and don't give most users access to turn it public.  Your approach makes little sense - you trust them to run your command but not to leave your repo private?

Comment: @matt that's not quite a duplicate since that question is about GitLab

Comment: @joanis I don't agree. The technique suggested is the technique to use (and indeed, in your answer you _do_ use it).

Comment: @matt Well, I am using the technique from the question itself rather than the technique from the answer, but fair point, I'm still using the technique from there, and so that Q&A as a whole can be considered an answer to this question here. I've just added a "Credits" link to it in my answer, since credit is indeed due here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `curl -I` to find out the status from fetching a web page without actually fetching it, and on GitHub you can fetch `https://github.com/user/repo` only if it's public.

So, if you run:

```
curl -I https://github.com/user/repo
```

and the status is 200, you know the repo is public, and you should not push to it.

Credits: my answer here is expanding on the idea described in this question: [Check if git repo is public with HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54959589/3216427)

##### My original scripting suggestion

To use this in a script, your could combine it with a grep:

```
if curl -I https://github.com/user/repo | grep "HTTP/2 200"; then
    echo repo is public, do not push
else
    echo repo is not public, yay
fi
```

Or, if you want to be safer, grep for 404 specifically instead of assuming not 200 is private:

```
if curl -I https://github.com/user/repo | grep "HTTP/2 404"; then
    echo repo is private, yay
else
    echo repo is public, do not push
fi
```

Caveat: GitHub returns 404 for both private repos and non-existent repos, so if you have a typo in the repo name, you'll also get a 404. But that's OK, because when you try to push to a non-existent repo on GitHub, the `git push` will error out with "fatal: repository  not found" so you still won't accidentally push your code where you don't want to.

##### Better scripting option

Using the answer from [Return only a HTTP status code from curl command](https://serverfault.com/questions/919036/return-only-a-http-status-code-from-curl-command), you can use `curl` to get the return code from fetching the page and save it into a variable to use in further logic:

```bash
HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -I https://github.com/user/repo -s -o /dev/null -w"%{http_code}")
if [[ "$HTTP_STATUS" == 200 ]]; then
    echo repo is public
elif [[ "$HTTP_STATUS" == 404 ]]; then
    echo repo is either private or does not exist
else
    echo HTTP status code $HTTP_STATUS, not sure what this means...
fi
```